# transpose rows and columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table like

```
Userid.   value1.   value2.    value3
1.           20.        10.      20
1.           10.         20.      5
2.           6.           5.        9
3.            7.          7.         0
```

When selecting I would like to get the result as

```
Userid.   1.      1.      2.       3
Value1.   20.    10.   6.       7
Value2.   10.     20.  5.      7
Value3.    20.    5      9.     0
```

The table will have n no of rows depending on the selection condition, how can I implement this.  I have multiple entries for a particular row id so how cud i do it

Comment: Can you please format your table data, I don't understand what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012? Don't add tags for both. At most you can include [tag:sql-server] and [tag:sql-server-2012] if you're using 2012.

Comment: You are looking for PIVOT or UNPIVOT!!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi strange thing is that even I know this, just by reading this site feature... And I never knew or used this

Comment: The strange thing is - a question about PIVOT is the first result you get if you Google "sql transpose".

Comment: I'm totally new to this requirement, all I need is total transpose of full rows and columns

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Real Transpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696225/sql-real-transpose)  or even [Convert multiple columns into a single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010754/convert-multiple-columns-into-a-single-row)

Comment: @Barmar I would actually suggest a dup that applies both unpivot/pivot.

Comment: The data don't look to me like they would be normalized either way.  Userid, valueid, value might be a better structure.

Comment: To be fair, this is a little different than some transpose questions since it has multiple entries for userid 1, but no effort seems to have been made.

Comment: SQL tables or query results cannot have duplicate columns. Instead, you should normalise your data in a way that lets you manipulate the data the way you need (userid/attribute/value).